# Opening multiple outlook windows on macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, ms-office

I'm running Microsoft Outlook on Mac Book Pro 2015.
How do I open multiple windows of it?
On windows I could open outlook multiple times.
Can i do this on Mac?

Comment: Can you try `File -> New -> Open New Main Window`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To open multiple windows, simply go to `File -> New -> Open New Main Window`.

This will allow you to open your calendar and your email is separate windows so you can see both at the same time.